# Spring Boot Find By <Column> Containing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I try to search by disease containing, I get the results, but only the first time that I run the code. After that I get the below error, do you know why this works on the first try then will always return this error with the same request? thanks!:

Good result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Simvastatina",
        "companyName": "Company1",
        "price": 5.55,
        "disease": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "expirationDate": "2023-12-31"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Simvastatina",
        "companyName": "Company1",
        "price": 5.55,
        "disease": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "expirationDate": "2023-12-31"
    }
]
```

Error:

```
2022-07-05 19:17:55.083 ERROR 4484 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [%Lorem%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Character (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%Lorem%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Character (n/a)]] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%Lorem%] did not
match expected type [java.lang.Character (n/a)] at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final] at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final] at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final] at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final] at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:501)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final] at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:122)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final] at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:393)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final] at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:61)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$BindableQuery.setParameter(QueryParameterSetter.java:319)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.lambda$setParameter$3(QueryParameterSetter.java:116)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$ErrorHandling$1.execute(QueryParameterSetter.java:141)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.setParameter(QueryParameterSetter.java:116)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:82)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:74)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:96)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.invokeBinding(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:324)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:243)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:106)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:227)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:128)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at com.fsdprogram.demo.controllers.medicine.$Proxy239.findByDiseaseContainingIgnoreCase(Unknown
Source) ~[na:na] at com.fsdprogram.demo.controllers.medicine.MedicineController.findMedicinesByDisease(MedicineController.java:60)
~[classes/:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
Source) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
Source) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2] at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2] at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2] at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2] at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2] at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2] at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Call:

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user/medicines/disease/Lorem

Entity:

```
package com.fsdprogram.demo.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Data
@Entity
public class Medicine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String companyName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Column(name = "disease",nullable = false)
    private String disease;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date expirationDate;
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.fsdprogram.demo.controllers.medicine;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.fsdprogram.demo.model.Medicine;

@Repository
interface MedicineRepository extends JpaRepository<Medicine, Long> {
    List<Medicine> findByName(String name);
    List<Medicine> findByDiseaseContainingIgnoreCase(String disease);
    List<Medicine> findByDiseaseStartingWith(String disease);
    List<Medicine> findByDiseaseLike(String disease);
    List<Medicine> findByDisease(String disease);
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.fsdprogram.demo.controllers.medicine;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import lombok.Data;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import com.fsdprogram.demo.model.Medicine;

@RestController
public @Data class MedicineController {
    private final MedicineRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@GetMapping("/api/user/medicines/disease/{disease}")
List<Medicine> findMedicinesByDisease(@PathVariable("disease") String disease) {
    return repository.findByDiseaseContainingIgnoreCase(disease);
}
```

}

Data:

```
INSERT INTO medicine (
        id, name, company_name, price, disease, expiration_date
    ) 
    VALUES (1, 'Simvastatina', 'Company1', 5.55, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit', '2023-12-31');

INSERT INTO medicine (
        id, name, company_name, price, disease, expiration_date
    ) 
    VALUES (2, 'Aspirina', 'Company2', 1.23, 'Sed non augue et leo interdum congue', '2024-12-31');

INSERT INTO medicine (
        id, name, company_name, price, disease, expiration_date
    ) 
    VALUES (3, 'Omeprazol', 'Company3', 7.55, 'omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium', '2025-12-31');

INSERT INTO medicine (
        id, name, company_name, price, disease, expiration_date
    ) 
    VALUES (4, 'Lexotiroxina sódica', 'Company4', 6.55, 'At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos', '2026-12-31');

INSERT INTO medicine (
        name, company_name, price, disease, expiration_date
    ) 
    VALUES ('Aspirina', 'Company3', 1.24, 'Seda non augue et leo interdum congue', '2025-12-31');

INSERT INTO medicine (
        name, company_name, price, disease, expiration_date
    ) 
    VALUES ('Simvastatina', 'Company1', 5.55, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit', '2023-12-31');
```

Comment: Please shorten the error message - it takes up too much of your post.

Comment: What database do you use, and what do the column definitions look like?

Comment: What version of hibernate/spring boot are you using?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, I reduced lines from the error message. The database is H2, but the error happened with SQL Server as well, the hibernate version is 5.6.7. 
Jens Schauder nailed the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug in Hibernate](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15142), which was also [reported against Spring Data JPA](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2472). On that issue [Greg Turnquist explains the workaround](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2512#issuecomment-1116666770):

> Workaround is to either pin Hibernate to an older, working version:
>
> ```
> <properties>
>    <hibernate.version>5.6.5.Final</hibernate.version>
> ```
>
> ...or if you don't want to go to an older version of Hibernate, to parameterize your repository...
>
> ```
> @Repository
> public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, String> {
>
>   List<Book> findByIsbnContaining(@Param("isbn") String isbn);
> }
> ```
>
> This forces query derivation to plugin the "right" parameter and hence not break at the Entity Manager.